# What would be regular Expression for validating Date format like mm/yyyy.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

What would be regular Expression for validating Date format like mm/yyyy. I am new to regular expressions

```
$.validator.addMethod(
"customDate",
function(value, element) {
    return value.match(?);
},
"Please enter a date in the format mm/yyyy"
);
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: With just regex you can easily validate for mm/yyyy format, but it'd consider invalid dates such as 99/9999 as valid without extra checks.

Comment: Extract the individual parts (month and year) and then ensure no outlier values, as noted above. **Since the function can contain arbitrary code, there is no reason to limit the solution to a single regular expression.** Instead, write something robust than you can understand [later].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on RobG's function:

```
function validateDate(s) {
  return /^([1-9]|1[0-2])\/[12]\d{3}$/.test(s);
}
```

`([1-9]|1[0-2])` checks it is either `1`-`9` or `10`-`12`.
`[12]\d{3}` makes sure the year is `1` or `2` followed by three numbers (so valid ranges in this case would be `1000`-`2999`; if you need more specific values, please update your question.

**EDIT**
If you want month values of 01-12 instead, change the regex to:

`/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[12]\d{3}$/`

Comment: Perhaps `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]` for the first bit, to allow for the `MM` specified (whether the leading `0` should be optional is up to the OP).

Comment: Yeah, originally it was that, but in the comment to RobG's answer, Krishh says "1-12", so I changed it.

Comment: Yeah, if the OP doesn't mind if it's `M` or `MM`, add the question mark after the `0` like nnnnnn says.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the your answer! You have given a very clear explanation on how the regular expression work. Thanks again..

Comment: You're more than welcome. Finally I've been able to help someone else instead of just asking questions all the time! Yay!

Answer (score 2):

What are your criteria for "valid"? Is `/^\d{2}/\d{4}$/` sufficient or do you need to check that the month is between 1 and 12 inclusive?

Also, it is much more appropriate to use test:

```
function validateDate(s) {
    return /^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(s);
}
```

or a more efficient version (only creates the regular expression once):

```
var validateString = (function() {
    var re = /^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
    return function(s) { return re.test(s);}
}());
```

Comment: I would require it to check for the months between 1 and 12.

Comment: Yes, I'd use `.test()`, too. But this regex allows values that aren't months, like 13, 99 and 00 (see my answer for an example of one that excludes non-valid values)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
var regex = /^(\d{2})[\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
```

After that, you could check the regex subgroups for out of bounds ranges like 1000 years from now, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
/^[01]?\d\/\d{4}$/
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first part allow month values like 13-19, though?

Comment: An optional 0 or 1 followed by a single digit allows 0-19. And "00".

Comment: Yeah, you're right, long day... brain dead. @David John Welsh 's looks like the best one.

Comment: Yeah, but with an optional `1` or `0` followed by `\d`, with no other criteria, 13-19 will return `true`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise nnnnnn (nice name, by the way :-D) had already said that.